# Defining a replacement for punctuators in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Several days ago, someone told me that their keyboard is faulty, leaving them unable to type `(` on their keyboard. The first thing that came to my mind, when writing C, was to either copy the character from somewhere and just paste it or to try to use preprocessor directive `#define` . Once I tried to use `#define`, I realised that gcc doesn't let me write something like `#define OB (` and I pretty much understand why. Is it possible to write something similar to this and let me replace a punctuator using `#define`?

Comment: Instead trying to tweak your code or compiler, you could tweak your OS by hooking keyboard inputs and simply map over to the desired symbol. I've done that in the past on a keyboard that were missing some keys.

Comment: Your friend might be interested in [Alternative operator representations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative).

Comment: While `gcc` can't understand `#define OB (` it can understand `-DOB='('`. Just tried that.

Comment: @Bauss I actually did that on Slackware and explained how to remap some keys on the keyboard so the problem is solved. This is more of a curiosity question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As far as I can see here, these do not cover parentheses?

Comment: @NMilev Ah that's true. The digraphs and trigraphs was invented for keyboards that don't have the "special" characters, and parentheses isn't really a "special" character in that way. The only (long term) solution I can see is to replace the keyboard.

Comment: @aragaer I suggest you post an answer but explain this in more detail with a small code example and I will consider this answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a trigraph for `(` I would suggest that. Otherwise your solution with a macro might work, but unfortunately when written in C or a header file it can not be parsed as you want it. However using `gcc` you can specify that macro directly using the `-D` option.

Example:

```
int main OB ) {
    printf OB "Hello, world\n");
}
```

I can compile it using the following command: `cc -o test test.c -DOB='('`. I needed to add `'` otherwise `bash` wouldn't accept that.

You can also use `make` adding the extra parameter to `CPPFLAGS`: `CPPFLAGS+="-DOB='('" make test` - again you need more quotes than usual otherwise all the shells would not understand unquoted `(`. Of course you can just add `CPPFLAGS+=-DOB='('` directly to the `Makefile`.

**Edit:**
In fact you can still have a macro in code. But you have to tell `gcc` that `(` is not a part of macro identifier. The following worked for me:

```
#define OB \
    (
int main OB ) {
    printf OB "Hello, world\n");
}
```